# how to add ListView with orientation as horizontal from code behind in uwp?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have to achieve this syntax from code behind how can I do that

```
    <ListView>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                     />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
```

in general how can I achieve property element syntax from code behind in uwp?

Comment: what you have above is not a listview with horizontal orientation, this is a listview with vertical orientation and the items within it have a stackpanel with horizontal orientation.

Comment: @ShawnRamirez my main problem is how can i write the above xaml in my code behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to add ListView with orientation as horizontal from code behind in uwp?

For making `ItemsPanelTemplate` in the code behind, you could parse `ItemsPanelTemplate` string and then pass it to ListView's `ItemsPanel`.

```
private void ApplyItemsStackPanelAsItemsPanel(ItemsControl itemsControl)
{

    var itemsPanelTemplateXaml =
        $@"<ItemsPanelTemplate xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
                          xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'>
           <ItemsStackPanel Orientation='Horizontal'/>
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>";

    itemsControl.ItemsPanel = (ItemsPanelTemplate)XamlReader.Load(itemsPanelTemplateXaml);

}
```

**Usage**

```
private void BuildListView()
{
    var listview = new ListView();
    ApplyItemsStackPanelAsItemsPanel(listview);
    listview.ItemsSource = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
    this.Content = listview;
}
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for, XamlReader.Load is this the only way to achieve this kind of syntax [property element syntax](https://www.noesisengine.com/docs/Gui.Core.XamlIntroduction.html#property-element-syntax)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it this way.

```xml
<ListView x:Name="AwesomeListView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}">
    <!--
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    -->
</ListView>
```

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public List<int> Items { get; set; } = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.AwesomeListView.ItemsPanel = CreateItemsPanelTemplate(Orientation.Horizontal);
    }

    ItemsPanelTemplate CreateItemsPanelTemplate(Orientation orientation)
    {
        string xamlString =
            $@"<ItemsPanelTemplate
                    xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
                    xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'>
                    <ItemsStackPanel Orientation='{orientation}' />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>";

        return (ItemsPanelTemplate)XamlReader.Load(xamlString);
    }
}
```